# Restore duplicity archive with entire path remembered

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, duplicity

Lets say I have two files that I want to separately backup: `/home/user1` and `/home/user2/`

This is easy:

```
duplicity /home/user1 file:///media/mateusz/Backup/user1_backup
duplicity /home/user2 file:///media/mateusz/Backup/user2_backup
```

I know that I can run

```
duplicity restore file:///media/mateusz/Backup/backup /unpack_path/home/user1
```

but it requires me to manually provide `/home/user1` path part. I want to change backup or/and extraction command so that it will be handled by duplicity.

**To avoid XY problem**:
My backup is split in multiple chunks, to reduce backup fragility and I prefer to not be forced to remember what exact path are stored in each chunk, because this duplicity version of backup is forcing me to increase chunk count, as

```
 duplicity [full|incremental] [options] source_directory target_url
```

may take only one `source_directory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy to solve. Backup `/` (yes, that's the file system root), but define in/excludes to only backup the folders you want eg.

```
--include '/home/user1' --exclude '**'
```

more info about in/excluding can be found on duplicity's [man page](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html).

Comment: It works (what is backuped and extracted is exactly the same), but it emits some new errors what is not wanted: "Error accessing possibly locked file /lost+found
Error accessing possibly locked file /root
(...)
Error '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/unpack_location/home'' processing ." Is it possible to somehow avoid them?

Comment: I am convinced that it is a Duplicity bug. I reported it as https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1571204